# Finding all integer solutions to equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This seems like a pretty simple problem and was wondering how to solve it.

I was thinking using the factorization theorem

Find all solutions to $m^2 - n^2 =105$, for which both $m$ and $n$ are integers

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$m^2-n^2=105\iff (m-n)(m+n)=3\cdot 5 \cdot 7.$$

Moreover, note that from the factorization of $105$ it has $8$ positive divisors: $$1,3,5,7,15,21,35,105.$$

And, even more, the possible factorizations of $105$ are $$1\cdot 105,\:3\cdot 35,\:5\cdot 21,\:7\cdot 15,\:(-1)\cdot (-105),\:(-3)\cdot (-35),\:(-5)\cdot (-21),\:(-7)\cdot (-15).$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $ m^2 - n^2 = (m-n)(m+n) $ and $ 105 = 3 \cdot 35 = 5 \cdot 21 = 7 \cdot 15 $.

Comment: You also have $105=1 \cdot 105$

Comment: Yes, this is true.